# Tengo error al usar php artisan migrate - laravel 7.X (siempre sucede tenga o no código hecho)

Tags: mysql, artisan, homestead, laravel-7

Descargué la ultima version de laravel con este comando

```
$ composer create-project laravel/laravel nombreProyecto
```

Además también usé Homestead

```
$ Composer require laravel/homestead
```

El problema es que haya tenido listo el código para la migración o no haya tocado nada de código, al usar el comando **php artisan migrate** me genera un error que siempre sucede.

les muestro el composer.json con las dependencias por defecto. adicionalmente esta el paquete ui que teambien lo descargué

```
...    
"require": {
        "php": "^7.2.5",
        "fideloper/proxy": "^4.2",
        "fruitcake/laravel-cors": "^1.0",
        "guzzlehttp/guzzle": "^6.3",
        "laravel/framework": "^7.0",
        "laravel/homestead": "^10.8",
        "laravel/tinker": "^2.0",
        "laravel/ui": "^2.0"
    },
...
```

esta es la sección de la base de datos en el .env por defecto

```
...
DB_CONNECTION=mysql
DB_HOST=127.0.0.1
DB_PORT=3306
DB_DATABASE=laravel
DB_USERNAME=root
DB_PASSWORD=
...
```

El error que me genera es este y siempre sucede con esta versión de paquetes que descargo

```
vagrant@apirestful:~/apirestful$ php artisan migrate

   Illuminate\Database\QueryException

  SQLSTATE[HY000] [1045] Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: NO) (SQL: select * from information_schema.tables where table_schema = laravel and table_name = migrations and table_type = 'BASE TABLE')

  at vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Database/Connection.php:671
    667|         // If an exception occurs when attempting to run a query, we'll format the error
    668|         // message to include the bindings with SQL, which will make this exception a
    669|         // lot more helpful to the developer instead of just the database's errors.
    670|         catch (Exception $e) {
  > 671|             throw new QueryException(
    672|                 $query, $this->prepareBindings($bindings), $e
    673|             );
    674|         }
    675|

  • Database name seems incorrect: You're using the default database name `laravel`. This database does not exist.

    Edit the `.env` file and use the correct database name in the `DB_DATABASE` key.
    https://laravel.com/docs/master/database#configuration

      +34 vendor frames
  35  artisan:37
      Illuminate\Foundation\Console\Kernel::handle()
```

Dentro de la maquina virtual se encuentran estas bases de datos por defecto

```
vagrant@apirestful:~/apirestful$ mysql
Welcome to the MySQL monitor.  Commands end with ; or \g.
Your MySQL connection id is 7
Server version: 5.7.29-0ubuntu0.18.04.1 (Ubuntu)

Copyright (c) 2000, 2020, Oracle and/or its affiliates. All rights reserved.

Oracle is a registered trademark of Oracle Corporation and/or its
affiliates. Other names may be trademarks of their respective
owners.

Type 'help;' or '\h' for help. Type '\c' to clear the current input statement.

mysql> show databases;
+---------------------+
| Database            |
+---------------------+
| information_schema  |
| homestead           |
| #mysql50#lost+found |
| mysql               |
| performance_schema  |
| sys                 |
+---------------------+
6 rows in set (0.05 sec)
```

Alguien tiene idea porque sucede esto, o sea esta algo claro que el nombre de la base de datos en el archivo .env no existe en las tablas de mysql lo cual es raro porque en unas versiones anteriores esto si coincide. Quiero saber si esto es normal que suceda y necesite una modificación o si es un error del framework o de mi parte, gracias de antemano

Comment: Cambiando los datos por los sugeridos en mi respuesta aún persiste el error?

Comment: ya no persiste el error, muchas gracias, al parecer esto se descarga asi por defecto y entonces hay que modificarlo manualmente.

Comment: Un gusto colabora, saludos!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Si estas utilizando `Homestead` de acuerdo a la documentación oficial [Click aquí](https://laravel.com/docs/4.2/homestead) los datos de acceso por defecto para la base de datos son:

```
DB_USERNAME=homestead
DB_PASSWORD=secret
```

Claramente tu problema es que tienes error en la autenticación por lo que espero esto te pueda ayudar. Saludos.